# Is this algorithm optimized? How else would it be used?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm working on a Project Euler problem ([number 15, lattice paths](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15)).  I've solved the problem another way, but I'm curious as to how to optimize the algorithm I used to initially try to solve the problem because it grows very quickly and am kind of surprised at how long it actually takes. So I really looking to learn how to analyze and continue to optimize the algorithm.

This algorithm's approach is to use the corners as points - `(0,0)` in top left, `(2,2)` in bottom left for a 2x2 grid. From the top point, the path will only be `x+1` or `y+1`.  So I pretty much iteratively form these paths by checking if the next allowable move exists in the space of points in the grid.

I initially started from the top left `(x+1, y+1)`, but found it to be more efficient to go backwards from the bottom, removed some redundancies, and start to store only the valuable data in memory.  So that's where I am now.  Can it be optimized any further? and what other types of applications would this have?

the `givenPoints` is a list of all the points in the grid, stored as a string - ie `'0202'`.  the algorithm stores the most recent point of the unique paths as opposed to the whole path, and at the end the number of entries in the list is equivalent to the number of unique paths.

```
def calcPaths4(givenPoints):
    paths = []
    paths.append(givenPoints[-1])
    dims = int(math.sqrt(len(givenPoints))) - 1
    numMoves = 2*dims
    numPaths = 0

    for x in range(0,numMoves): 
        t0= time.clock()  
        newPaths = []
        for i in paths:
            origin = int(i)
            dest1 = origin - 1
            dest3 = origin - 100
            if ('%04d' % dest1) in givenPoints:
                newPaths.append(('%04d' % dest1))
                numPaths +=1
            if ('%04d' % dest3) in givenPoints:
                newPaths.append(('%04d' % dest3))
                numPaths +=1
        t= time.clock() - t0
        paths = newPaths
        print(str(x)+": " +str(t)+": " +str(len(paths)) )
    return(paths)
```

Comment: Sounds like you can better ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean (2,2) in bottom right?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an improved on this algorithm. Instead of creating every single unique path and then counting them all you can only keep track of the number of paths for each coordinate and compute how many pass through coordinate `(x,y)` using the counts for `(x+1, y)` and `(x, y+1)`.   This is called dynamic programming.

Comment: Yes, bottom right.  my bad.
thanks for the answers! very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You've got the wrong approach. Starting from the top left going to the bottom right corner takes 20 moves to the right and 20 moves down.

So you can think *any* path as a sequence of length 20 with 10 elements that are `right` and 10 elements that are `down`. You simply have to count how many arrengements are there.

Once you have fixed the, say, `right` moves the `down` ones are fixed, so the whole problem reduces to: *in how many ways can you choose 10 positions from a set of 20?*

This is simply solved by the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Hence a solution is:

```
from math import factorial

def number_of_paths(k):
    """Number of paths from the top left and bottom right corner in a kxk grid."""
    return factorial(2*k)//(factorial(k)**2)
```

Which can be made more efficient by noting that `n!/(k!*k!) = (n·(n-1)···(k+1))/k!`:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def number_of_paths(k):
    """Number of paths from the top left and bottom right corner in a kxk grid."""
    return reduce(op.mul, range(2*k, k, -1), 1)//factorial(k)
```

---

Note that the number of paths grows rapidly, which means **any** algorithm that works by *creating* the different paths is going to be slow. The only way to seriously "optimize" this is to change approach and avoid creating the paths but just counting them.

---

I''l point out a different, more general, approach: *recursion* and memoization/dynamic programming.

When the path is at a certain position `(x,y)` it can either go right to `(x-1,y)` or go down to `(x, y-1)`. So the number of paths from that point to the bottom right is the sum of the number of paths that reach the bottom right from `(x-1,y)` and those that reach the bottom right from `(x, y-1)`:

Base case is when you are on the edge, i.e. `x==0` or `y==0`.

```
def number_of_paths(x, y):
    if not x or not y:
        return 1
    return number_of_paths(x-1, y) + number_of_paths(x, y-1)
```

This solution follows your reasoning, but it only keeps track of the number of paths. You can see that again it is very inefficient.

The problem is that when we try to compute `number_of_paths(x, y)`
we end up doing the following steps:

- Compute `number_of_paths(x-1, y)`

  - This is done by computing `number_of_paths(x-2, y)` and `number_of_paths(x-1, y-1)`
- Compute `number_of_paths(x, y-1)`

  - This is done by computing `number_of_paths(x-1, y-1)` and `number_of_paths(x, y-2)`

Note how `number_of_paths(x-1, y-1)` is computed *twice*. But the result is obviously the same! So we can just computing it the first time and the next time we see that call we return the already known result:

```
def number_of_paths(x, y, table=None):
    table = table if table is not None else {(0,0):1}
    try:
        # first look if we already computed this:
        return table[x,y]
    except KeyError:
        # okay we didn't compute it, so we do it now:
        if not x or not y:
            result = table[x,y] = 1
        else:
            result = table[x,y] = number_of_paths(x-1, y, table) + number_of_paths(x, y-1, table)
        return result
```

And now this executes pretty fast:

```
>>> number_of_paths(20,20)
137846528820
```

You could think "performing a call twice, isn't a big deal" but you have to take into account that if the call for `(x-1,y-1)` is computed twice, for each time it does two calls for `(x-2, y-2)` thus resulting in computing `(x-2, y-2)` *four* times. And then `(x-3, y-3)` *eight* times, ... and then `(x-20, y-20)` *1048576 times*!

Alternatively we could have built a `kxk` matrix and fille it from the bottom right:

```
def number_of_paths(x, y):
    table = [[0]*(x+1) for _ in range(y+1)]
    table[-1][-1] = 1
    for i in reversed(range(x+1)):
        for j in reversed(range(y+1)):
            if i == x or j == y:
                table[i][j] = 1
            else:
                table[i][j] = table[i+1][j] + table[i][j+1]
    return table[0][0]
```

Note that here the table represents the intersections so we end up with a `+1` in the sizes.

This technique of memorizing previous call to reuse them later is called memoization. A more general principle is dynamic programming where you basically reduce the problem to filling a tabular data structure as we did here, using recursion and memoization and then you "backtrack" on the cells by using pointers you filled earlier to obtain a solution to the original problem.

Comment: do you have a link that explains why/how the kxk matrix works? thanks!

Comment: @jf2qm It's basically same reasoning. Think of the 20x20 grid as a 19x19 grid (that is the bottom-right part) plus a new row and a new column. Assume you know the results for the number of parts in the 19x19 matrix: how would you fill the new row and column? You could do the same thing with an asymmetric matrix: extending a 3x20 matrix to a 4x20 matrix adding the top row (which is what the code does).  Anyway if you search for "dynamic programming" you'll find plenty of material and applications for this.